# I accidentally deleted my Gemfile. Can I recover it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I accidentally deleted my Gemfile `rm Gemfile`
Can I recover it or recreate one?

Comment: You should use a version control system like *git*

Comment: I do. I just realized that! What is the git command to grab only the Gemfile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use git (as you said in the comments):

```
git checkout -- Gemfile
```